# Why my toolbar doesn't hide when SearchView action appears?

Tags: android, toolbar, searchview

[This is my toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo1nU.jpg)

I am trying to create a search toolbar with Search ActionView, but when I opening the search bar the title of my toolbar is not being hidden. I tried to add in the menu.xml showAsAction = "collapseActionView" but it remains the same.

Here is my code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name="com.apps.screens.ContactsActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Activity.java

```
public class ContactsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private List<Contact> items;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ContactPhoneAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
}

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contacts_menu, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
}
```

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".screens.ContactsActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:title="Select Contact"
            android:background="@color/white" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_contacts" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I appreciate any suggestion

Answer (score 4):

In this piece of code , add the following line of code

`searchview.maxWidth  = Integer.MAX_VALUE`

```
@Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contacts_menu, menu);

       MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
       SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
        searchview.maxWidth  = Integer.MAX_VALUE // add this line of code 
       searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
               return false;
           }

           @Override
           public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
               adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
               return false;
           }
       });

       return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Save my lots time. I am very confused with this. and you make my problem solution in just one line. Thank you very much